# Command so that anyone within a radius who isn't me gets teleported?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-commands

I know [r=x] is to make a radius and you can do /tp @a[r=30] x y z to teleport someone everyone 30 blocks away but how can I do it so it excludes me? So let's say that me and two other people are standing 10 blocks away from the command block, how could I make it that it teleports everyone else apart from me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `name=!YOUR NAME` to the selector. So if your username is `Chickenator`, you should do:

```
/tp @a[r=30,name=!Chickenator] x y z
```

The `!` excludes or negates the selection value. You can also exclude teams, using `team=!TEAM`, for example if you want to exclude all staff (OP players), you can put them in a team and exclude that team. Another use for the `!`, is `type=!ENTITY TYPE`, for example, `type=!Cow`, to exclude cows.

Comment: Works great! I can also use @e instead of @a to quickly get rid of any mobs :D

Comment: @Chickenator Glad it helped you :D